# How to reach VMware host from guest without changing IP address all the time

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion, hosts

I have no trouble *accessing* my VMware host from the guest (as covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61449/how-do-i-access-the-host-machine-from-the-guest-machine), for example).  That's easy.

But once I've set up my (Windows) guest's `hosts` file to point to my (OS X) host's IP address, the IP invariably eventually changes, and going in and editing the host file in Windows all the time is tedious and painful.  How can I set up an IP address that can be consistently available from the host to the guest, even when other IPs change.

(Or, if this is already done, how do I identify which of my IPs is the one that is supplied by VMware and will not change?)

Any proposal which prevents my guest from accessing anything other than my host will not actually work for my use case.  The guest needs to be able to access other network resources (which it can currently do).  So (as far as I understand) that would mean a host-only setting is a non-starter.  I'm currently using NAT.

Using `MyMacsName.local` will not work, because the app I'm working on (through no fault of my own) was built to require a specific hostname.  (Please don't tell me to change this, as it's not something I have authority to change.)

Setting up all DHCP servers on all networks I ever use to always give me a specific IP address is not realistic.  (If nothing else is *possible*, I suppose I could do this with both home and work networks, but that would be a horrible kludge, in my opinion, forcing me to change my home network segment to whatever is used at work, and reconfigure everything else that has a specific IP assigned, and depends on using a specific IP.)

The host computer gets its IP through DHCP.  The guest computer through whatever mechanism VMware uses when using the NAT network setting.

Comment: Are you assigning the VM a static address or using DHCP to assign it?

Comment: I'm not sure how the VM's IP is determined, but does that matter?  Isn't the host IP the only one that matters?  Both are on `172.16.*`, so it is possible that the guest just uses DHCP like the host. But I don't think so, since I'm using NAT and not Bridged Networking.  As far as I understand, the guest is isolated from the outside network.  But still, can you explain why it would matter?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear in the question, I'm trying to hit a server on my *host* from the *guest*, so that I can test in IE and NVDA, even though my main development is done on OS X.

Comment: Yes;  It does matters.  Update your question to reflect that information once you determine which it is.

Comment: can you explain why the guest's IP matters?

Comment: @iiconoclast - It is the reason you have to keep changing your hosts file.

Comment: no, I have to change my hosts file because the IP of the *host* changes, not the *guest*.

Comment: I already know your hosts file is changing because of the host os, so what are you changing it from and to, provide specific examples.